# Parsing link from table with PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing

I'm using the following code to parse table elements from the Australian Securities Exchange:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();  


//load the html  
$html = $dom->loadHTMLFile("http://www.asx.com.au/asx/statistics/prevBusDayAnns.do");  

  //discard white space   
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;   

  //the table by its tag name  
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');   

    //get all rows from the table  
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');   
  // get each column by tag name  
$cols = $rows->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('th');   
$row_headers = NULL;
foreach ($cols as $node) {
    //print $node->nodeValue."\n";   
    $row_headers[] = $node->nodeValue;
}   

$table = array();
  //get all rows from the table  
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');  

foreach ($rows as $row)   
{   
   // get each column by tag name 

    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td'); 

    $companysymbol = $cols->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $pubtime = $cols->item(1)->nodeValue;
    $newstitle = $cols->item(3)->nodeValue;

    $row = array();

    echo $companysymbol . '<br>';
    echo $pubtime . '<br>';
    echo $newstitle . '<br><br>'; 

}

?>
```

The code is working fine, but in addition to echo the $companysymbol, $pubtime and $newstitle I would like to echo the link (PDF link) inside the table. Can someone tell me how?

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the `href` attribute, and then recreate link.

```
(...)
$pdflink = $cols->item(5)->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE ? $cols->item(5)->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href') : '';
(...)
echo "<a href='http://www.asx.com.au$pdflink'>pdf</a>".'<br>';
```

This will create clickable link to pdf.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but unfortunately your solution would echo the word "PDF" and not the link itself (href inside <a> tag).

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thanks 1000 times!